# How to wrap uninterrupted text in Latex?

Tags: latex, margin, word-wrap, phylogeny

I need to insert text like this in my Latex document:

((((tetrameristaceae,pellicieraceae),marcgraviaceae),balsaminaceae),(fouquieriaceae,polemoniaceae,sladeniaceae,(ternstroemia,adinandra)pentaphylacaceae,(schima,gordonia)theaceae,(lissocarpa,diospyros)ebenaceae,symplocaceae,(maesaceae,(theophrastaceae,(primulaceae,(myrsine,ardisia)myrsinaceae))),(diapensiaceae,(parastyrax,styrax)styracaceae),sapotaceae,(barringtonia,gustavia)lecythidaceae,(((ericaceae,cyrillaceae),(purdiaea,clethra)clethraceae),(sarraceniaceae,((actinidia,saurauia)actinidiaceae,roridulaceae)))))ericales;

Latex writes the all text in one line, going way off in the right margin. I cannot use \linebreak by hand, this just gives a poor result when the text is longer, and it would be a lot of work given all the similar text to include.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Your question lacks the definition of the desired outcome, so I'll just try to guess.

Simplest idea: just add spaces after each comma.

Comment: And as a bonus, it looks better too.

Answer (score 6):

You could add hyphenation hints in the text: if you put `\-` in a word (for example `non\-breaking`) LaTeX will break only at those position but will break at those positions if necessary. You'll get a hyphen at the breaking position though.
Another possible option might be using the [hyphenat](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyphenat/) package and defining the comma as your hyphenation character. As I never used that package myself I might be wrong here though.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it, but it looks like the [newicktree](http://cbr.jic.ac.uk/dicks/software/newicktree/) package may be of some interest to you.  The article [PHY·FI: fast and easy online creation and manipulation of phylogeny color figures](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/1471-2105-7-315) and the associated [web-based tool](http://cgi-www.daimi.au.dk/cgi-chili/phyfi/go) also seem like they would be helpful.

---

**EDIT**: I found a way to more or less accomplish what you want by using a package in a way that it almost certainly was not intended.  Here is the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\url{((((tetrameristaceae,pellicieraceae),marcgraviaceae),balsaminaceae),(fouquieriaceae,polemoniaceae,sladeniaceae,(ternstroemia,adinandra)pentaphylacaceae,(schima,gordonia)theaceae,(lissocarpa,diospyros)ebenaceae,symplocaceae,(maesaceae,(theophrastaceae,(primulaceae,(myrsine,ardisia)myrsinaceae))),(diapensiaceae,(parastyrax,styrax)styracaceae),sapotaceae,(barringtonia,gustavia)lecythidaceae,(((ericaceae,cyrillaceae),(purdiaea,clethra)clethraceae),(sarraceniaceae,((actinidia,saurauia)actinidiaceae,roridulaceae)))))ericales;}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[IMAGE http://img230.imageshack.us/img230/4705/newick.png](http://img230.imageshack.us/img230/4705/newick.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution that gets part of the way there (as far as I can tell). It doesn't require any changes to the markup, but allows you to insert extra spaces if you like automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\comma{,}
\newcommand\openbrace{(}
\newcommand\closebrace{)}
\begingroup
\catcode`\,=\active
\catcode`\(=\active
\catcode`\)=\active
\gdef\weird{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\,=\active
  \catcode`\(=\active
  \catcode`\)=\active
  \def,{\comma\allowbreak}%
  \def({\openbrace\allowbreak}%
  \def){\closebrace\allowbreak}%
  \processweird
}
\endgroup
\newcommand\processweird[1]{#1\endgroup}
\weird{((((tetrameristaceae,pellicieraceae),marcgraviaceae),balsaminaceae),(fouquieriaceae,polemoniaceae,sladeniaceae,(ternstroemia,adinandra)pentaphylacaceae,(schima,gordonia)theaceae,(lissocarpa,diospyros)ebenaceae,symplocaceae,(maesaceae,(theophrastaceae,(primulaceae,(myrsine,ardisia)myrsinaceae))),(diapensiaceae,(parastyrax,styrax)styracaceae),sapotaceae,(barringtonia,gustavia)lecythidaceae,(((ericaceae,cyrillaceae),(purdiaea,clethra)clethraceae),(sarraceniaceae,((actinidia,saurauia)actinidiaceae,roridulaceae)))))ericales;}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can put whitespace between nodes and have the usual linebreaks.  You can also introduce optional hyphenations (with a hyphen) by inserting `\-` in the words.

If you (or whoever has to approve your work) insists on arbitrary breaks, perhaps you can use the [seqsplit](http://ctan.org/pkg/seqsplit) package.